# checkbox status

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

```
function saveData()
{    
    var rows = $('#deviceTable tr').length;    
    var toSave = "";

    alert(rows);

    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i ++)
    {               
        alert('inside for loop');

        if($("#saveDevName_"+(i)).attr('checked'))
        {

            alert('sving the data');

            toSave+=$("#devName_"+(i)).text()+",";              
        }           
    }       
}
```

`($("#saveDevName_"+(i+1)).attr('checked'))`--- is not executed.Hence not checking the status.If statement is not executed {if($("#saveDevName_"+(i)).attr('checked'))}
Plz suggest me the right approch.

Comment: Is it not executed, or not returning `true`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
if($("#saveDevName_"+(i)).attr('checked'))
```

With:

```
if($("#saveDevName_"+(i)).is(':checked'))
```

More Info:

- http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery 1.6 then you need to either use `is(":checked")` as suggested by Sarf or use `prop` instead of `attr`.  As of 1.6 `attr("checked")` is going to return the attribute value which was set when the page loaded.

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Prior to 1.6 I believe using `attr("checked")` would have worked as you expected.